# tns doctor not working. WARNING: There was a problem with CocoaPods

Tags: nativescript

I tried installing Nativescript on my machine and successfully ran all the commands but when I ran TNS doctor I got the following error.

`Verifying CocoaPods. This may take more than a minute, please be patient.
Installing iOS runtime.tns-ios@2.1.1 ../../var/folders/pr/zxhdgq354w36_v4jnkyg89fr0000gn/T/nativescript-check-cocoapods11679-71167-clmpmh/node_modules/tns-ios
Verifying CocoaPods. This may take some time, please be patient..
sandbox-exec: /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/bin/pod: Operation not permitted
WARNING: There was a problem with CocoaPods
Verify that CocoaPods are configured properly.
There seem to be issues with your configuration.`
1

I have googled around for a fix but could not get any answer e.g. https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/1943

There was a mention of chmodding ./Pods but that didn't work. Has anyone else had this problem and fixed it?

I have installed and checked cocoapods but it still yields the same error.
`Last login: Tue Aug  9 19:24:23 on ttys000
XXX-MacBook-Air:~ mine$ sudo gem install cocoapods
    Password:
    Successfully installed cocoapods-1.0.1
    Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.0.1
    Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 4 seconds
    1 gem installed
    XXX-MacBook-Air:~ mine$ pod --version
    1.0.1`

`

Answer (score 1):

Install your CocoaPods with superuser permissions.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

And then check if they are installed correctly

```
pod --version
```

Also, you might want to update your XCode version if you are using older one.
Refer to [this issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/1782#issuecomment-223986634) for similar problem discussed.

Comment: Yes i tried that but still have the same problem with TNS doctor after
`
Last login: Tue Aug  9 19:24:23 on ttys000
sudo gem install cocoapods
XXX-MacBook-Air:~ mine$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.0.1
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.0.1
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 4 seconds
1 gem installed
XXX-MacBook-Air:~ mine$ pod --version
1.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

You will need a lower version of cocoapods first you will need to remove your current version `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` then you can proceed to install

`sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6 
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.39.0`

After installing cocoapods you can try creating a demo app and run it

`tns create demoApp
cd demoApp
tns run ios`

You can ignore `tns doctor` for now

Comment: Thanks mate, I do this but get the following error

`MacBook-Air:demoApp xxx$ tns run ios --emulator
Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
# run ios`

Comment: What is the output of `tns --version`

Comment: "You are using CocoaPods version 0.39.0 which does not support Xcode 8.0 yet." 
Faced the issue

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found the right answer (at least for me) and paste it for future references.

currently using:

MacOs Sierra with
xcode: v7.3.0 
cocoapods: v1.0.1
nativescript: v2.3.0
node: v6.8.1

Steps:

- Locate your `node_modules` folder where your global npm packages are installed (I am using `nvm` version manager and `node v6.8.1` so it was `/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v6.8.1/lib/node_modules/nativescript/config`).
- open `node_modules/nativescript/config/config.json`
- Change the value of `USE_POD_SANDBOX` to `false`

Reason (as act of faith): NativeScript uses the sandbox-pod executable. This may prevent some pods from installing correctly. If you encounter such cases, you can switch to the regular pod executable.

original source: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/1943#issuecomment-246186556

Answer (score 0):

[Cocoapods problems][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCWVI.png
[continue Cocoapods problems][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/trSvT.png
[continue Cocoapods problems][3]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwvhK.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).